# AS3 Crossdomain imageload

Tags: actionscript-3

Actually i have to load images into stage from any server,
 so tried using crossdomain.xml from my server root.

though it throughs error

> SecurityError: Error #2122: Security sandbox violation:
>   Loader.content: http://sss/Player.swf cannot access
>   http://ffff/images/logo-bg.jpg. A policy file is required, but the
>   checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded.  at
>   flash.display::Loader/get content()   at
>   SS4UPlayer_fla::MainTimeline/ss4uLogoCompleteHandler()

Whats the problem, Please can you find it.

Answer (score 0):

**import flash.system.LoaderContext;**

Using this LoaderContext i just got clear my problem and loaded config.xml under my root directory.